# Google Language Translator - Manage Translation

Tags: plugins, translation

I installed [Google Language Translator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/) wordpress plugin. How can I manage it's translation (https://translate.google.com/manager/website).

I can manage the translation if not using a plugin, but instead manually adding the code provided by google translate.

Comment: The Plugin's [support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/google-language-translator) might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hi JR Galia, I'm the plugin creator for Google Language Translator....you probably won't be able to manage personal settings through the Google interface while using the plugin, only because I'm not familiar with any API currently available to do this. If anyone has a suggestion as to how I could do this, I would surely add this to the plugin.